# Ошибка при создании директории

Tags: c++

[image: C]

Жалуется на путь., пытался гуглить , но не помогло, у всех были другие ошибки

Comment: Приведите код и ошибку в текстовом виде. Используйте `<filesystem>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `CreateDirectoryA`. У вас `CreateDirectory`, почему то вызывает `CreateDirectoryW`(скорее всего метод `CreateDirectory` является оркестровым и он проверяет аргумент на `unicode`)

короче так работает:

```
CreateDirectoryA("C:\\test123", nullptr);
```

или если использовать CreateDirectoryW:

```
CreateDirectoryW(L"C:\\test1235", nullptr);
```

почитать про различие двух методов и про такие аргументы они внутрь себя принимают:

[msdn CreateDirectoryA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya)

[msdn CreateDirectoryW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectoryw)

P.S. так и есть идет проверка на `Unicode` :

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateDirectory  CreateDirectoryW
#else
#define CreateDirectory  CreateDirectoryA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

так что надо быть аккуратным!

Comment: А как указать имя папке?

Comment: @DockedFerret800 при указании пути вы и так указываете название папки. например в моем примере я создал папку test123 на диске C:

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте L перед Вашим путем. Собственно на это и жалуется. Получится где то так `(L"E:\\`